# The complete name of the double colon in C++

Tags: c++

If I have a class:

```
class A{
public:
    A();
    void print();
private:
    int value;
};

A::A() {value = 0;}
void A::print() {cout << value << endl;}
```

What is the complete name of the :: symbol in the last 2 lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 15):

> What is the complete name of the `::` symbol in the last 2 lines?

It's "scope resolution operator".

> Does anyone know the answer?

Yes.

> Is this the weirdest question you ever been asked?

No.

Comment: I like this answer very much.

Comment: On the downside, and with exceptionally poor timing, while you were typing this I edited the superfluous copy out of the question!

Comment: It would be great if you put it back again.

Comment: This is how to answer a question with style.

Comment: I thought it was about something you can use instead of "::", like `A.this->A()` or something.

Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's called [scope resolution operator.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr175.htm)

---

You'd like to know what you could write *instead* of `::`? Well, there is no alternative that always works. For your example, it is possible to just define those member functions in the body of your class, that would be the inline-style of defining a class:

```
class A{
  int value;
 public:
  A() {
    value = 0;
  }
  void print() {
    cout << value << endl;
  }
};
```

That way, you obviously have no way to put the definition in a different file, so it's not possible to compile them separately.

At other times, when `::` is used to resolve a *`namespace`* rather than a `class`, you can replace that with [either reopening that namespace or pulling it into scope with `using namespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928686/best-practices-using-namespace-or-reopen-namespace).

Comment: How about `#define SCOPE ::`? ;)