# C++ Namespace around header declaration and source definition

Tags: c++, namespaces, coding-style, declaration

I am making a static library, everything defined in it is all in one namespace. But I am unsure whether I should define the methods as if you would a class, or also wrap them in the namespace. What I'm asking is:

Is this valid:

MyThings.h

```
namespace MyThings {
    void DoStuff();
    void DoOtherStuff();
}
```

MyThings.cpp

```
namespace MyThings {
    void DoStuff() {
        // Do this.
    }

    void DoOtherStuff() {
        // Do that.
    }
}
```

Or, should I define it like I would class methods?:

MyThings.cpp

```
void MyThings::DoStuff() {
    // Do this.
}

void MyThings::DoOtherStuff() {
    // Do that.
}
```

I would prefer not to use `using namespace MyThings;`, and I would prefer to use my first example if it is valid, I feel it makes the code more readable without having to use `MyThings::` before every method identifier.

Comment: Both variants works equally well. It's up to you how you want it.

Comment: Related (and offers discussion of the third option): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928686/best-practices-using-namespace-or-reopen-namespace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are valid, so you can pick your style according to taste.

There is an advertised advantage of defining the function using:

```
void MyThings::DoStuff() {
    // Do this.
}
```

which is that in order to do it, the function must have already been declared. Thus, errors like:

```
void MyThings::DoStuf() {
    // Do this.
}
```

or

```
void MyThings::DoStuff(int i) {
    // Do this.
}
```

are caught when you compile `MyThings.cpp`. If you define

```
namespace MyThings {
    void DoStuff(int i) {
        // Do this.
    }
}
```

then you generally won't get an error until someone in another source file tries to call the function, and the linker complains. Obviously if your testing is non-rubbish you'll catch the error one way or another, but sooner is often better and you might get a better error message out of the compiler than the linker.

Comment: +1 for the "must have been declared". for some strange reason i've never thought of that.

Comment: +1. Great answer, answers the question and tells me the implications of using my desired way of defining the functions in the namespace. I had never thought of that either.

Comment: +1 Good point about the link time error. I hadn't even considered that.